# iOS - allow app to receive image from another app

Tags: uiimage, uiactivity

We'd like to allow developers to send an image to our app via a UIActivity.

How can we set up our app to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to register the file types it supports. To register for a file type your app must include the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in its Info.plist property list file. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) for more information.

```
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>My File Format</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
       <array>
           <string>MySmallIcon.png</string>
           <string>MyLargeIcon.png</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
       <array>
           <string>com.example.myformat</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: This will make your app available from the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. There is no way to make your app available in the UIActivityViewController, which is where UIActivity instances are used.